# Wordpress: prevent mod_rewrite rules for specific directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to install a CakePHP app in the same directory as a Wordpress site. The CakePHP app only has a couple controllers, so I think this should be possible by adding a few `RewriteCond`s. Unfortunately the following /.htaccess file isn't working correctly:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#start my additions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
#end my additions

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#CakePHP rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

For some reason, the Wordpress stylesheets aren't getting found:

`GET http://example.dev/wp-content/themes/sow3/style.css?1365621024 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cakephp rules are rewriting the static content. Try adding some conditions for the rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-includes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Aha! The first block seems to have solved it! You were right 100% correct that cake's rules were getting the static content. That was confusing me because all the other WP pages were working.